# How can i edit word files inside my windows forms app?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005, windows-forms-designer

I need to edit word templates inside my windows forms app, how can i do that? is there any control to do it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This used to be possible, no longer.  OLE embedding is dead as a doornail.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;en-us;304662

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to host Word itself inside a WinForms application, but I doubt you want to do that.

Depending on your requirements you may want to use a third-party control for editing word files. There are many out there, so check with your favorite component provider.

Alternatively you could just launch Word outside your application and respond to when it's window is closed or when the template file is modified. This will probably be much easier and more stable than running hosting Word in winforms.

Comment: Hi Rune, thanks very much for your advice, but my customer want to edit word files inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the web browser control to host office documents. There was talk about a `ActiveDocumentHost` control but it seems it got canned.

Comment: Hi, where i can find the ActiveDocumentHost control? i've looking in my visual studio 2005 toolbox and it does not appear there.

Comment: It seems it never got put in in the first place.